# Jest not transforming imported typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs, babeljs

I am not using ts-jest. [According to this guide](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started), I shouldn't have to in order to test my typescript modules.

I have a simple project setup with jest and typescript. [You can see the code here](https://github.com/tedconn/ts-test).

When I run `jest`, I am always getting an error like the following:

```
[ts-test] jest
 FAIL  src/__test__/index.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    /Users/tconn/dev/ts-test/src/index.ts:9
      static type = "something";
                  ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

    > 1 | import Animal from '../index'
        | ^
      2 |
      3 | describe('generate', () => {
      4 |   it('does something', () => {

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:451:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/__test__/index.spec.ts:1:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.411s
Ran all test suites.
```

Essentially it seems like the imported class is not being transpiled to JS but the test is. As the jest site indicates, I have the right settings in my babel config.

Comment: `This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.` Why should it be able to parse `.ts` when you don't give it any transformer to do so? Why not use `ts-jest`?

Comment: Why do I need a dependency when jest says they support TS out of the box?

Comment: Jest supports TypeScript, via Babel. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-typescript. So you need to config babel preset and include .ts or .tsx extension for babel-loader

Comment: As of today, Jest has a `ts-jest` option that doesn't require (or use by default) babel. I'm still getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you are missing a babel config, or the babel config does not have the presets or plugins required for nodejs to interpret your code. Review [Jest Getting Started: Using TypeScript](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript) to see what you did wrong.

- Make sure your babel config file is named correctly e.g. babel.config.json, or .babelrc.json or js, cjs, mjs, or in package.json as described in [Babel Config Files](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files). [Print the effective Babel config](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration#print-effective-configs) using `BABEL_SHOW_CONFIG_FOR=src/__test__/index.spec.ts npx jest` to make sure the your babel file is being used.
- Make sure your babel config contains `@babel/preset-env` and `@babel/preset-typescript` in the presets, or some other preset that includes the [@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-modules-commonjs)
   plugin among other things.